# CodeIgniter outputting multiples of the same row

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

How can I keep the foreach statement from outputting multiple's of the same row? I need it to just output all the rows that meet the Sql requirement one time. Any ideas?

```
$query  = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM churchMembers WHERE cMuserId = '{$userid}'");
$row = $query->row();
$membersChurchId = $row->cMchurchId;
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT wp.entryData, u.firstname, u.userid
                           FROM wallPosts wp, users u
                           WHERE wp.wpChurchId = '{$membersChurchId}'");
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    echo $row->entryData.nl2br("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

After discussing the problem, it was the problem with the query.
The correct query in your case will be

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT wp.entryData, u.firstname, u.userid FROM users u INNER JOIN wallPosts wp on wp.postingUserid = u.userid WHERE wp.wpChurchId = '{$membersChurchId}'");
```

---

I think you are approaching this the wrong way.If you need to output all the rows, that meet your requirements, at one time, then you have to create a function, which reads the rows and build the output. But still you will be using the foreach

```
function buildAll($result) {
     $output = "";
     foreach($result as $row) { 
         $output .= $row->entryData."<br />"; //no need for nl2br("\n")
     }
     return $output;
}
```

Now include this function in a helper or whatever you like as use it in your code like

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT wp.entryData, u.firstname, u.userid
                           FROM wallPosts wp, users u
                           WHERE wp.wpChurchId = '{$membersChurchId}'");

echo buildAll($query -> result()); //in one show
```

---

However the method I wrote above is only good, when you are using the function in more than one occasion

Comment: I'm still getting multiple rows.

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby, I thought you wanted to display multiple rows without the foreach. Now the only explanation is , you are getting muliple from the query. do a var_dump($query -> result()) and post it on your question.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/csGHYsA2 - its not suppose to be outputting so many 'Hi' and 'hello'.

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby, looks like, you are getting duplicate rows from the database. I think duplicate were inserted in the database, while testing. Run the sql command directly form `phpmyadmin` to confirm what i am saying.

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/photos/68017617@N06/6814511818/ - as you can see there are only 2 entries in the table.

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby, but you are using two table `wallPosts` and `users`. Are you sure you ran the actual query from your posted code above

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8613/discussion-between-starx-and-michael-grigsby)

Comment: Yes. And that is something I've noticed. http://www.flickr.com/photos/68017617@N06/6814520036/ - Notice how I get two of the same rows returned. Why would it be doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.. I'm also having this issue... I haven't found any solution on how to get rid of the duplicate items on the array. but i have a temporary remedy for our problem.

use this:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $key => $row) {
    if($key%2 == 1){
        echo $row->entryData.nl2br("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I suggest:

1) change `foreach` to $key => $row and print the $key and $row. I remember sometimes I got duplicate entries where one $row had a $key and the other didn't. If this is an issue, try `result_array()` instead of `result()`. Assuming that looks normal, I'd do....

2) Make sure `cMuserId` and `wpChurchId` are primary keys. Otherwise, they might have duplicate entries?